# useEffect not reloading when the dependency is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I am trying to display the screen size on my page and every time the size changes with a drag I want the size on the screen to change as well while dragging the window.

Can someone explain to me why this does not work. As much as I understand if I add something in the dependencies array in useEffect, it should look for a change in that value, and once it changes it should do whatever is inside it and refresh the page. So by dragging the window "window.innerWidth" changes, why doesnt it trigger to update the page and display the new width?

```
    const [currentWindowWidth, setcurrentWindowWidth] = useState(
        window.innerWidth,
    );
    const [currentWindowHeight, setcurrentWindowHeight] = useState(
        window.innerHeight,
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        setcurrentWindowHeight(window.innerHeight);
        setcurrentWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }, [window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]);
```

in my return:

```
<h1> -- {currentWindowWidth}x{currentWindowHeight} </h1>
```

I found this solution on the internet that works, but I want to understand my does my logic not work, as it makes sense to me.

```
const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
        setcurrentWindowHeight(window.innerHeight);
        setcurrentWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
        };
    }, []);
```

Comment: You should set the dependencies as `currentWindowWidth` and `currentWindowHeight` instead.

Comment: @code it doesn't work , it does not refresh whenever the page size changes

Comment: It looks like you're creating an infinite loop. Your effect is just setting itself, you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: This is due to the fact that React does not track `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`, it has no way of knowing when they change and it has no way of knowing that your component relies on them. By using the event listener code in the snippet you found you are using events triggered on the window (not React) to update the React state variables when a change occurs. The `useEffect` in the event listener snippet is only being used to setup and remove the event listener and does not directly modify the state values (the event handler does this).

Comment: Was about to post but Jacob beat me too it. That is exactly right.  React only re-renders when either props or state changes. `window.innerHeight` and width are neither of those things. When they change, the component will not re-render and so it never gets as far as even evaluating the deps of the effect.

Comment: @JacobSmit so the event listener is added on resize, and it call my method to update the state value, then after its done it removes the event listener. But when the resize happens again, how does it know to call my function again, it we remove the event listener after the first resize?

Comment: The empty dependency array (`[]`) on the `useEffect` means that it will add the listener on component mount and remove the listener on component dismount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event listener in the useEffect hook in order to call your function when it happens, it would look something like this:

```
// Create your function with whatever you need to do with the width/height
const windowResized = () =>{
  console.log({height: window.innerHeight, width: window.innerwidth});
}
    
// Register your listener in the useEffect hook
useEffect(() => {
  const handleResize = () => windowResized();
    
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      
  // Do not forget to clear the listener when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }
}, []); //Call it just once
```